# The only possible one-dimensional representations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Proposition: Let $\phi, \psi : G \to \mathbb{C}^{*}$ be one-dimensional representations. $\phi \sim \psi \Leftrightarrow \phi = \psi. $

Construct $n$ inequivalent one-dimensional representations $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{C}^{*}$ and explain why your representations are the only possible one-dimensional representations.

For construct this is representations define $\phi^{(j)}: \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{C}^{*}$ where $\phi^{(j)}_{\bar{m}} = e^{\frac{2k_{j}\pi im}{n}}$, with $0<j<n$ and $0<k_{j}<n-1$. As $$ \phi^{(j)}_{\bar{m}} \neq \phi^{(l)}_{\bar{m}} \Leftrightarrow e^{\frac{2k_{j}\pi im}{n}} \neq e^{\frac{2k_{l}\pi im}{n}} \Leftrightarrow k_{j} \neq k_{l}.$$ Then by proposition $\phi^{(j)}_{\bar{m}} \nsim \phi^{(l)}_{\bar{m}}$.

Are the fact that these representations are unique in the fact of irreducibility? How do I know that any other representation I set is always equivalent to these n representations?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic with generator $1$, any representation is determined by $\phi(1)$. And you listed all the possible values of $\phi(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation are unique since if $e$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/n$, (the class of $1$) $\phi(e)^n=1$, so $\phi(e)$ is a $n$-root of unity.